# Isomorphism between injective resolution

Tags: homological-algebra, exact-sequence

When reading homological theory, I confront with a statement as follow.

In an exact sequence of $A$-modules:   $0\to M\to U_0\to U_1\to \dots\to U_{n-1}\to C\to0$  with all $U_i$ injective, and let $I$ be an ideal of $A$, we have $\operatorname{Ext}^1_A(A/I, C) \cong \operatorname{Ext}^{n+1}_A(A/I, M)$.

I am not sure how can one get this isomorphism. I guess if we give $C$ an injective resolution, we can expand the original exact sequence, right? Hope someone can explain. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is several way to see this. I will write two of them. The first rely on the notion of hyper-derived functor while the second is more elementary.

**First method :**
Consider the sequence of complexes
$$0\to M[0]\to U_\bullet\to C[-n+1]\to 0$$
where $M[0]$ is $M$ placed in degree $0$ and $C[-n+1]$ is just $C$ placed in degree $n-1$.
Concretely this is :
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
M[0]:@.0@>>> M@>>>0\\
@VVV@.@VVV\\
U_\bullet:@.0@>>>U_0@>>>U_1@>>>...@>>>U_{n-1}@>>>0\\
@VVV@.@.@.@.@VVV\\
C[-n+1]:@.@.@.@.0@>>>C@>>>0
\end{CD}
$$
Now this is not strictly speaking a short exact sequence of complexes, but a so-called distinguished triangle, which means that $\operatorname{Cone}(M[0]\to U_\bullet)\to C[-n+1]$ is a quasi-isomorphism.

This is enough to conclude that there will be a distinguished triangle 
$$ R\operatorname{Hom}(X,M)\to R\operatorname{Hom}(X,U_\bullet)\to R\operatorname{Hom}(X,C)[-n+1]\to$$
or if you don't know derived categories, a long exact sequences 
$$ ...\to \operatorname{Ext}^i(X,M)\to \operatorname{\mathbb{Ext}^i}(X,U_\bullet)\to\operatorname{\mathbb{Ext}}^i(X,C[-n+1])\to\operatorname{Ext}^{i+1}(X,M)\to...$$
Now, $\operatorname{\mathbb{Ext}}^i(X,C[-n+1])=\operatorname{Ext}^{i-n+1}(X,C)$ since this is just a complex concentrated in a single degree. Also $\operatorname{\mathbb{Ext}}^i(X,U_\bullet)=H^i(\operatorname{Hom}(X,U_\bullet))$ because $U_\bullet$ is a complex of injectives. It follows that if $i\geq n$, then $      \operatorname{\mathbb{Ext}}^i(X,U_\bullet)=0$.

And that's it. Just take $i=n$, the long exact sequence gives :
$$0\to\operatorname{Ext}^1(X,C)\to\operatorname{Ext}^{n+1}(X,A)\to 0$$$$$$$$
so you have the desired isomorphism.

---

**Second method** : More elementarily, you can use the standard trick in homological algebra which consists in splitting the sequence in short exact ones. Here this gives :
$$0\to M\to U_0\to Z_1\to 0$$
$$0\to Z_1\to U_1\to Z_2\to 0$$
$$\vdots$$
$$0\to Z_{n-1}\to U_{n-1}\to C\to 0$$
Where $Z_i=\ker(U_i\to U_{i+1})=\operatorname{im}(U_{i-1}\to U_i)$. Now, the long exact sequences associated to each of these short exact sequences give isomorphisms
$$\operatorname{Ext}^{n+1}_A(X,M)=\operatorname{Ext}^{n}_A(X,Z_1)=\operatorname{Ext}^{n-1}_A(X,Z_2)=...=\operatorname{Ext}^{2}_A(X,Z_{n-1})=\operatorname{Ext}^{1}_A(X,C)$$
(Use the fact that $U_i$ in injective so $\operatorname{Ext}^k_A(X,U_i)=0$ for any $k>0$).

In particular, with $X=A/I$, we get the desired result $\operatorname{Ext}^{n+1}_A(A/I,M)=\operatorname{Ext}^{1}_A(A/I,C)$.

Comment: I want to know more about those dimension shifting tricks. Could you explain how to get the short exact sequence you wrote above?

Comment: @YuyiZhang Sure but which one ? The very first exact sequence (a short sequence of complexes) or the breaking of the long exact sequence into short ones ?

Comment: The short sequence of complexes.

Comment: @YuyiZhang Done, note that I say short exact sequence of complexes where I should have said distinguished triangle. This is corrected.

Comment: Thank you really much! It seems a little advanced to me now. And I have one more question. How does the mapping cone come into the picture? It looks a little different from what I learn from Wikipeida.

Comment: Technically, the long exact sequence from the first method can be construct from more elementary considerations : consider $I_\bullet$ an injective resolution of $C$, and $J_\bullet$ the injective resolution of $A$ we get by juxtaposing $U_\bullet$ and $I_\bullet$ as you suggested in your post. Then you really have a short exact sequence of complexes $0\to I_\bullet[-n]\to J_\bullet\to U_\bullet\to 0$. Apply $Hom(X,.)$ to this short exact sequence. It will remain a short exact sequence of complexes because they were complexes of injectives, and then take the long exact sequence in cohomology.

Comment: Are you implying my guess in the post maybe work?

Comment: Sure it can, take the long exact sequence of complexes as in my previous comment and identify each term. The answer in my post is maybe more conceptual, but indeed require more knowledge in homological algebra (derived categories and hyper-derived functor...)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by induction on $n$. For $n=0$, the long exact sequence yields
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\H}{Hom}\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{Ext}
\E_A^1(L,U_0) \to \E_A^1(L,C)\to \E_A^2(L,M)\to \E_A^2(L,U_0)
$$
where the first and last terms are zero by injectivity of $U_0$.

For the induction step, split the resolution as
$$
0\to M\to U_0\to\dots\to U_{n-1}\to C'\to 0\\
0\to C'\to U_n\to C\to 0
$$

Note that the statement holds for any $A$-module $L$, not just for $L=A/I$.